# Need a regex pattern to match date with optional time

Tags: ruby, regex, datetime

**I need a regex pattern which matches a date with optional time.**

The date should be a valid U.S. date in `m/d/yyyy` format.  The time should be `h:mm:ss am/pm` or 24-hour time `hh:mm:ss`.

> Matches:  9/1/2011 | 9/1/2011 10:00 am | 9/1/2011 10:00 AM | 9/1/2011 10:00:00

This pattern will be used in a Ruby on Rails project, so it should be in a format usable via Ruby.  See http://rubular.com/ for testing.

Here's my existing date pattern (which may be an over-kill):

```
DATE_PATTERN = /^((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0[469])|([469])|(11))[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(30)))|((2|02)[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9]))))[\/]\d{4}$|^\d{4}/
```

Comment: If you stare at it long enough it's a sailboat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's what I ended up with; using stricter military time:

```
DATE_TIME_FORMAT = /^([0,1]?\d{1})\/([0-2]?\d{1}|[3][0,1]{1})\/([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1}|[2-9]{1}\d{3})\s([0]?\d|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$/
```

> Matches:  1/19/2011 23:59:59
>
> Captures:
>
> 1. 1
> 2. 19
> 3. 2011
> 4. 23
> 5. 59
> 6. 59

Answer (score 9):

Regular expressions are horrible for this kind of job. If you're using Ruby I'd recommend using [DateTime.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) to parse the data and check its validity:

```
def validate_date(date_str)
  valid_formats = ["%m/%d/%Y", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %P"] 
  #see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime for more

  valid_formats.each do |format|
    valid = Time.strptime(date_str, format) rescue false

    return true if valid
  end

  return false
end
```

Comment: Well, your approach seems like a valid alternative.  However, I'm dealing with existing code which is setup to use regex patterns. A custom DSL based on: [Create Your Own Programming Language](http://createyourproglang.com)

Answer (score 1):

```
if subject =~ /\A(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(?:\d{4})(?:\s+(?:(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)|(?:0?\d|1[0-2]):(?:[0-5]\d)\s+[ap]m))?\s*\Z/i
    # Successful match
```

Good luck..

How it works :

```
    "
^                       # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?:                     # Match the regular expression below
                           # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      0                       # Match the character “0” literally
         ?                       # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      [1-9]                   # Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9”
   |                       # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      1                       # Match the character “1” literally
      [012]                   # Match a single character present in the list “012”
)
/                       # Match the character “/” literally
(?:                     # Match the regular expression below
                           # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      0                       # Match the character “0” literally
         ?                       # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      [1-9]                   # Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9”
   |                       # Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      [12]                    # Match a single character present in the list “12”
      \d                      # Match a single digit 0..9
   |                       # Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      3                       # Match the character “3” literally
      [01]                    # Match a single character present in the list “01”
)
/                       # Match the character “/” literally
(?:                     # Match the regular expression below
   \d                      # Match a single digit 0..9
      {4}                     # Exactly 4 times
)
(?:                     # Match the regular expression below
   \s                      # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      +                       # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (?:                     # Match the regular expression below
                              # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         (?:                     # Match the regular expression below
                                    # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
               [01]                    # Match a single character present in the list “01”
                  ?                       # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
               \d                      # Match a single digit 0..9
            |                       # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
               2                       # Match the character “2” literally
               [0-3]                   # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “3”
         )
         :                       # Match the character “:” literally
         (?:                     # Match the regular expression below
            [0-5]                   # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5”
            \d                      # Match a single digit 0..9
         )
      |                       # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         (?:                     # Match the regular expression below
                                    # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
               0                       # Match the character “0” literally
                  ?                       # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
               \d                      # Match a single digit 0..9
            |                       # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
               1                       # Match the character “1” literally
               [0-2]                   # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “2”
         )
         :                       # Match the character “:” literally
         (?:                     # Match the regular expression below
            [0-5]                   # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5”
            \d                      # Match a single digit 0..9
         )
         \s                      # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
            +                       # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
         [ap]                    # Match a single character present in the list “ap”
         m                       # Match the character “m” literally
   )
)?                      # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s                      # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *                       # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$                       # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

Remember is not the spoon that bents but you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with that seems to work:
`regex = /^1?\d{1}\/[123]?\d{1}\/\d{4}(\s[12]?\d:[0-5]\d(:[0-5]\d)?(\s[ap]m)?)?$/`