# Rails regex won't work, but Javascript regex does

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, regex

I've read this question and changed my rails model code accordingly:
[Regular expressions with validations in RoR 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759735/regular-expressions-with-validations-in-ror-4)

Here's my regex for my datetime in rails:

```
/\A((19[7-9][0-9])|(2[0-9][0-9][0-9]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\s(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-4]))\:([0-5][0-9])\z/
```

This regex below works in javascript, though:

```
/^((19[7-9][0-9])|(2[0-9][0-9][0-9]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\s(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-4]))\:([0-5][0-9])$/
```

I'm trying to pass a datetime string to them both, but I can't understand why it keeps failing. Here's the string:

```
2014/12/02 11:06
```

I thought my model code might be helpful:

```
validates :start, presence: true, format: { :with => /\A((19[7-9][0-9])|(2[0-9][0-9][0-9]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\s(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-4]))\:([0-5][0-9])\Z/, :message => "must be in this format: YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM" }
validates :finish, presence: true, format: { :with => /\A((19[7-9][0-9])|(2[0-9][0-9][0-9]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\s(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-4]))\:([0-5][0-9])\Z/, :message => "must be in this format: YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM" }
```

**Edit: I figured out what the issue is, but I still don't know how to fix it...**

For some reason when I submit my form the date `2014/12/24 16:19` is being cut down to just `2014`. This then fails validation and throws the error.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: your regexp for ruby is correct, and it matches the provided string

Comment: Works for me: http://rubular.com/r/FoRXQm9t4H

Comment: @August I think my text_fields might be adding a new line to the end of the string. I tried adding a newline to the code you provided and it failed. Is there a way I can strip the newlines before submitting?

Comment: I think rails is cutting my input down to just the year for some reason. I don't know why, though

Comment: I figured out the problem: my datetime is being cut down to just the year (or anything before the first "/" I assumed) before being validated. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `regexp` for ruby part is correct, and it matches the provided string:

```
re = /\A((19[7-9][0-9])|(2[0-9][0-9][0-9]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\s(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-4]))\:([0-5][0-9])\z/
'2014/12/02 11:06' =~ re # => 0
```

Some **notes**:

1. See the `SO` topics [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978510/regex-to-match-date), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155153/need-a-regex-pattern-to-match-date-with-optional-time), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173548/validating-date-format-using-regular-expression) with explanation on how to match date in `ruby`.
2. Use regexp online services [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/), or [rubyxp.com](http://rubyxp.com/) to validate regexp match for `ruby` language, embedded [irb](/questions/tagged/irb) app, or debug [pry](/questions/tagged/pry) gem.